# Derivation of the position of wave packet

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, wavefunction, fourier-transform

As shown in [PRB 53 7010](https://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.53.7010) section II.A, the wave packet $W_0$ can be constructed from the superposition of Bloch states $\Psi_\mathbf{k}(\mathbf{r}) = e^{i\mathbf{k \cdot r}} u_\mathbf{k}(\mathbf{r})$
$$
|W_0\rangle = \int d^2\mathbf{k} w(\mathbf{k}) \Psi(\mathbf{k})
$$
where $w(\mathbf{k})$ is the envelop function. Then, it is shown that the mean position of the wave packet $W_0$ is (Eq 2.5)
[image: Eq 2.5]
I don't quite understand the first term in the square bracket in the second line of the above equation. Is it the derivative of the delta function? Where does it come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the term comes from
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{k}} \delta(\mathbf{k-k^\prime}) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{k}} \langle \Psi(\mathbf{k^\prime}) | \Psi(\mathbf{k}) \rangle = \langle \Psi(\mathbf{k^\prime}) | \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{k}}|\Psi(\mathbf{k}) \rangle
$$